# Creating ranged mapping records from yearly entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table that maps an ID to an Associated ID (AssocID) over time and the database is built having one record per year. I would like to roll up the table have one record for each period of association.

Current Example:

```
    ID AssocID Start End
    1  a       2000  2001
    1  a       2001  2002
    1  b       2002  2003
    1  b       2003  2004
    1  a       2004  2005
    ...
    1  a       2017  2018
    2  c       2000  2001
    2  c       2001  2002
    2  d       2002  2003
    ...
    2  d       2017  2018
```

and I am trying to make it look more like this:

```
    ID AssocID Start End
    1  a       2000  2002
    1  b       2002  2004
    1  a       2004  2018
    2  c       2000  2002
    2  d       2002  2018
```

My main problem is that ID '1' goes back to AssocID 'a' after time and using DISTINCT (ID, AssocID) and MIN (Start) misses the second time ID '1' maps to AssocID 'a'

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Tag properly!!!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server.  Which one is this?????

Comment: Also what have you tried so far???

Comment: @Eric - meant sql server, thanks for catching that. I've tried using joins to create a min table and max table then select where exists from the main table to those smaller ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this.

```
 -- Sample Data

 DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (ID INT, AssocID VARCHAR(10),  Start INT, [End] INT)
 INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES
(1, 'a', 2000, 2001),
(1, 'a', 2001, 2002),
(1, 'b', 2002, 2003),
(1, 'b', 2003, 2004),
(1, 'a', 2004, 2005),
(1, 'a', 2017, 2018),
(2, 'c', 2000, 2001),
(2, 'c', 2001, 2002),
(2, 'd', 2002, 2003),
(2, 'd', 2017, 2018)

-- Query 

SELECT ID, AssocID, MIN(Start) [Start], MAX([End]) [End] FROM 
    ( SELECT *, 
        GRP = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Start) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, AssocID ORDER BY Start)
     FROM @MyTable ) T
GROUP BY ID, AssocID, GRP
ORDER BY ID,  [Start]
```

Result:

```
ID          AssocID    Start       End
----------- ---------- ----------- -----------
1           a          2000        2002
1           b          2002        2004
1           a          2004        2018
2           c          2000        2002
2           d          2002        2018
```

Comment: This is beautiful and exactly what I needed. If its not too much, could you please explain how this works? I'm new to sql and would love to learn more.

thanks!

Comment: Before group the data with ID and account, you also need an extra field for the distinguished rows that have the same account but separated dates. 
To make this I used two row_count functions, one for ID and the other for ID and Account. And subtraction of this numbers gave me what I need.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a gaps and islands problem. You need to first identify the start of each group `grp_start` and then `group by` each `grp` to find the `min` / `max`

```
declare @T table (ID int, AssocID varchar(3), Start int, [End] int)
insert into @T (ID, AssocID, Start, [End]) values
(1, 'a', 2000, 2001),(1, 'a', 2001, 2002),(1, 'b', 2002, 2003),(1, 'b', 2003, 2004),(1, 'a', 2004, 2005),(1, 'a', 2005, 2006),(1, 'a', 2006, 2007),(1, 'a', 2007, 2008),(1, 'a', 2008, 2009),(1, 'a', 2009, 2010),(1, 'a', 2010, 2011),(1, 'a', 2011, 2012),(1, 'a', 2012, 2013),(1, 'a', 2013, 2014),(1, 'a', 2014, 2015),(1, 'a', 2015, 2016),(1, 'a', 2016, 2017),(1, 'a', 2017, 2018),(2, 'c', 2000, 2001),(2, 'c', 2001, 2002),(2, 'd', 2002, 2003),(2, 'd', 2017, 2018)


select 
    ID,
    AssocID,
    min(Start),
    max([End])
from
(
    select *,
        sum([grp_start]) over (partition by ID, AssocID order by [End]) as grp
    from
    (
        select *,
            case 
                when
                    lag([End]) over (partition by ID, AssocID order by [End]) <> [Start] 
                then 1 else 0
            end as [grp_start]
        from @T
    ) as T
)as T
group by ID, AssocID, grp
order by ID, min(Start), max([End])
```